# Get dynamically-created Controls in CURRENT page

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, this, httpcontext

I need to access a dynamically created Control.

I am not being able to get it with FindControl.

I guess it's because the method is being triggered by AJAX.

So my question is:

How to access from C# code behind the dynamically generated Controls (must use FindControl) in the CURRENT page?

I tried *this* and *HttpContext.Current.Handler* but the controls don't seem to come attached.

This is the sequence:

1. User clicks sort of a *Like* dynamically-created LinkButton
2. There is a JS listener to all those LinkButtons that *on click* changes text to *Dislike* (example) and does an AJAX POST to aspx page trigerring its method MyClick().
3. MyClick() would use `FindControl("labelXX")`.Text and set it.

I would want something like:

```
((Label)((System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).FindControl("lblXX")).Text = "foo";
```

EDIT:
I have a EventHandler added to each LinkButton, i want to access from there.

Comment: You can not find the control using the ajax call from client side. You need to set return type where the particular text which you are trying to set will be return from that AJAX call. and find that label,change the text.

Comment: How are you dynamically creating the LinkButtons?

Comment: Are you using ajax framework ? it might change the id of the textbox...can you see the source as html and see what is the id and give the id in FindControl

Comment: Hi, i edited my post to be more specific. @Ricketts: new LinkButton() and set different IDs for each. It's finding the Label Control when the Method() is called that is being the problem. All IDs are "ContentPlaceHolder1_MyLabel_" + postid

Comment: @Dillinger are you trying to do ajax call and server side event both at the same time?

Comment: Is the EventHandler firing? If so, you should have an (object sender) param. Can't you simply do `LinkButton mybutton = (LinkButton)sender;`?

Comment: Just code: Yes, the LinkButton has a JS onclick listener that performas an AJAX call. Ricketts: Yes it's firing, but i want to update a LABEL that is in the same PAGE as the LINKBUTTON, not the LinkButton. That's why i want (Label)Page.FindControl("MyLabel") to work.

Comment: If it is your js ajax method that creates the label you're trying to find, it won't be available in the code behind. How are the labels added to the page? If they are hard coded in the HTML, you should have direct access to them unless they are inside of a Repeater control (or other control) that you must perform the `FindControl` on label's parent.

Comment: All controls are being generated dynamically (in code behind). I just don't understand why it's so hard to get the controls of the page we're actually in.